# Android Studio: Can not write to the Storage of my device, even though it seems to find the path just fine

Tags: android, android-studio

So, I am trying to make a little GPS Tracker, which works fine so far. I get the data, put it into a .kml file and then I want to save the file to the storage. I can see in my android console that it creates the file just fine. But when I then try to save it to storage, it always throws a file not found exception.

This is the class that should do the exporting and saving:

```
private void doExport() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            // Hard code to set altitudeCorectionMeters
            this.setAltitudeCorrectionMeters(40);

            db = openOrCreateDatabase(GPSLoggerService.DATABASE_NAME,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * " + " FROM "
                    + GPSLoggerService.POINTS_TABLE_NAME
                    + " ORDER BY GMTTIMESTAMP ASC", null);
            int gmtTimestampColumnIndex = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("GMTTIMESTAMP");
            int latitudeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("LATITUDE");
            int longitudeColumnIndex = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow("LONGITUDE");
            int altitudeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ALTITUDE");
            int accuracyColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ACCURACY");
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                StringBuffer fileBuf = new StringBuffer();
                String beginTimestamp = null;
                String endTimestamp = null;
                String gmtTimestamp = null;
                initFileBuf(fileBuf, initValuesMap());

                // Write coordinates to file
                do {
                    gmtTimestamp = cursor.getString(gmtTimestampColumnIndex);
                    if (beginTimestamp == null) {
                        beginTimestamp = gmtTimestamp;
                    }
                    /**
                     * 2. getData from database (cursor);
                     */
                    double latitude = cursor.getDouble(latitudeColumnIndex);
                    double longitude = cursor.getDouble(longitudeColumnIndex);
                    double altitude = cursor.getDouble(altitudeColumnIndex)
                            + this.getAltitudeCorrectionMeters();
                    double accuracy = cursor.getDouble(accuracyColumnIndex);

                    /**
                     * End step 2.
                     */

                    /**
                     * 3. Write data (query from database) to file
                     */
                    fileBuf.append(sevenSigDigits.format(longitude) + ","
                            + sevenSigDigits.format(latitude) + "," + altitude
                            + "\n");

                    /**
                     * End Step 3.
                     */
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                endTimestamp = gmtTimestamp;
                closeFileBuf(fileBuf, beginTimestamp, endTimestamp);

                String fileContents = fileBuf.toString();
                Log.d(tag, fileContents);

                /**
                 * Step 4. Write file to /sdcard
                 */

                File sdDir = new File("/sdcard/GPSLogger");
                sdDir.mkdirs();
                File file = new File("/sdcard/GPSLogger/" + currentTripName
                        + ".kml");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                FileWriter sdWriter = new FileWriter(file, false);
                sdWriter.write(fileContents);
                sdWriter.close();

                /**
                 * End Step 4.
                 */
                // R.string.export_completed Predefined in string.xml
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.export_completed,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // If cursor.moveToFirst() Fails, no data is available
                // database
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        "I didn't find any location points in the database, so no KML file was exported.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                File sdDir = new File("/sdcard/GPSLogger");
                sdDir.mkdirs();
                File file = new File("/sdcard/GPSLogger/" + currentTripName
                        + ".kml");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getBaseContext(),
                    "Error trying access the SD card.  Make sure your handset is not connected to a computer and the SD card is properly installed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                File sdDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED).getPath());
                String pathname = sdDir.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pathname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Error trying to export: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                close_db(db);
            }
        }
```

The path to:

```
File sdDir = new File("/sdcard/GPSLogger");
```

is hardcoded, because otherwise the App only finds the emulated storage. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Everything seems to work fine, until it shall save the file to the actual storage...

The Toast message from the exception also seems to show a valid path+name combination. I would be very grateful for help.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot!

I forgot to give it permission to write to my storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

That fixed it for me.
:)